# Proposition about convergence of an increasing sequence

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis

Proposition says

> An increasing sequence $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$ is convergent if and only if it is bounded above.

Is it true for two directions? If it is, how should I begin to proof? I need some hints.

Thanks a lot

Comment: A monoptonic sequence converges if and  only if it as bounded. If it is an increasing sequence, it converges to its least upper bound; if it is decreasing, it converges to its greatest lower bound.

Answer (score 0):

It says "if and only if" that means you will need to prove both directions.

Proving it one way is snap.

A convergent sequence is bounded

We have a finite sequence, (and finite sequences are bounded) and we have a tail where all of the points in the tail are close to one another.

Doesn't matter that it is monotone

Proving it the other way.

A monotone sequence that is bounded.

It has a convergent sub-sequence.  Every element in the tail of the sub-sequence are close to one another. And since it is monotone the intervening members of the sequence are close to one another.